# How to solve Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.sql.Statement.executeUpdate in Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, netbeans

I am doing a simple bus ticket management project. For that purpose i want to add the system user data in the database. But my problem is ,it is showing that the code has an error in the following line in netbeans.

```
 int executedQuery=statement.executeUpdate();
```

If the code is compiled with error then the following error message in  showing

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.sql.Statement.executeUpdate
    at airlinessoft1301d.User_New.add_jButton1ActionPerformed(User_New.java:367)
    at airlinessoft1301d.User_New.access$100(User_New.java:21)
    at airlinessoft1301d.User_New$2.actionPerformed(User_New.java:255)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

compiler error output :

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
D:\Farhad_BusTicketManagement\src\airlinessoft1301d\User_New.java:369: error: no suitable method found for executeUpdate(no arguments)
          int executedQuery=statement.executeUpdate();
    method Statement.executeUpdate(String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Statement.executeUpdate(String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Statement.executeUpdate(String,int[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Statement.executeUpdate(String,String[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Note: D:\Farhad_BusTicketManagement\src\airlinessoft1301d\User_New.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
1 warning
D:\Farhad_BusTicketManagement\nbproject\build-impl.xml:946: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Farhad_BusTicketManagement\nbproject\build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The entire source code has given below. Though i have done some other database insert work in the same manner and they worked. Please anyone tell me where i have made the mistake.

I am using Netbeans GUI builder to create the user interface.
Netbeans version is 8.1
jdk 1.8_60.

Previously i was using netBeans 7.3. In the internet saw that netBean 7 has a bug that it may show such error. Then i have installed netbeans 8.1. but the problem is same.

Computer generated code has not given.

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    /**
     *
     * @author Cybertrons
     */

    public class User_New extends javax.swing.JFrame {


        public User_New()
        {
            initComponents();
        }


    //start of loadingDriver(). This method will be called where driver loading is needed.
        public void loadingDriver()
        {
            try
            {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
            {
                    Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    //End of loadingDriver(). This method will be called where driver loading is needed

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")//computer generated code not given.

 private void name_jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                

    private void add_jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        //Just for checking that add button is working.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Clicked...!");

 //   Start of Varriable Decaliration.
        String userID;
        String name;
        String birthDate;
        String phone;
        String email;
        String gender;
        String userName;
        String password;
        String position;
//   End of Varriable Decaliration.     

//  Strat of Reading vlaue form text fields.
        userID      =userId_jTextField1.getText();
        name        =name_jTextField1.getText();
        birthDate   =birth_Date_jTextField2.getText();
        phone       =phone_jTextField3.getText();
        email       =email_jTextField4.getText();
        gender      =Gender_jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        userName    =userName_jTextField5.getText();
        password    =pass_word_jPasswordField1.getText().toString();
        position    =position_jTextField7.getText();
//  End of Reading vlaue form text fields.

        Connection connection   = null;
        Statement  statement    = null; 

//The driver will loaded here by calling the method loadingDriver(), That has defined above.
        loadingDriver();

// start of inserting data into database.
        try //inseritng try block.
        {
//            connecting to databse.
            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/busticket", "root", "");            
//            Insering to database.
            statement = (PreparedStatement) 
                    connection.prepareStatement("insert into newuser (userID,name,birthDate,phone,email,gender,userName,password,position) values"
                  + "(NULL ,'"+userID+"','"+name+"','"+birthDate+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"','"+gender+"','"+userName+"',"
                    + " '"+password+"','"+position+"')");

            //To ensure that the query has executed successfully.
          int executedQuery=statement.executeUpdate();

//  Start of making the text fields Empty
            if(executedQuery==1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Inserted Success fully....!");
              //start of setting emplty string at the text fields.
                   userId_jTextField1.setText("");
                   name_jTextField1.setText("");
                   birth_Date_jTextField2.setText("");
                   phone_jTextField3.setText("");
                   email_jTextField4.setText("");
                   userName_jTextField5.setText("");
                   pass_word_jPasswordField1.setText("");
                   position_jTextField7.setText("");
            //end of setting emplty string at the text fields.
            }
//  End of making the text fields Empty

//      Start of  Closing Databae Connection.
            if(statement!=null)
            {
                statement.close();
            }
            if(connection!=null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }
//      end of      Closing Databae Connection.

        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
// end of inserting data into database.
    }                                            


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(User_New.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(User_New.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(User_New.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(User_New.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new User_New().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: 1. Never try to run code that does not compile correctly. 2. Post your complete **compiler** error message in this situation, not the runtime exception stacktrace. Indicate clearly which line(s) cause the error.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, i have added the compiler error message.

Comment: You're wanting to call a PreparedStatement's `executeUpdate()` method, one that takes no parameters, but are calling it on a Statement variable, not a PreparedStatement variable. If the object is in fact a PreparedStatement, then make the variable one too.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, its working. if u kindly post ur comment as answer, i will take  it  as answer.

Comment: Thank you, but Mureinik posted a similar answer almost simultaneously, and so OK to accept his answer. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) doesn't have an `execute()` method. [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), on the other hand, does. Your `statement` varaible is in fact a `PreparedStatement` (in runtime), but you're storing it in a `Statement` variable, so the code won't compile. Just store it in a `PreparedStatement`, and you should be OK:

```
PreparedStatement  statement    = null;
```

Note that the explicit casting when you prepare the statement is also redundant:

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into ... etc");
```